# SharePoint 2010 List disabling edit even for people with Manage permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

this seems to be a bit of an odd requirement, but we have a separate form (not an infopath form) being filled out by people. Now, this form that we have has quite a lot of validations in it. We're currently trying to prevent people from accessing the list where this certain form is saving the data, this is so that they won't bypass the validations we created in the form that we created. Is there a way to be able to do this, one way or another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix.  Use SharePoint Designer to browse to the list, starting from "All Files".  The list has several files in it.  You're only interested in NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx.

Open these files.  Either add JavaScript redirect code directly to the file (near placeholdermain) to point back to AllItems.aspx, or add a Content Query Web Part to add the redirect JavaScript code in that added web part.

Either way, when users go to add/edit items in that list, they will be bounced back to the page that list the items.

This will only work when JavaScript is enabled.  Mind you, SP won't work very well with JavaScript off anyway, so people may not disable JS.  But for a bullet proof solution, make a Visual Studio feature for the specific list.

Comment: The VS feature won't work as we don't have any access to the server itself (corporate SharePoint) so that won't be viable, but with the JS, I'll try that one on my end.